# Linked List Insertion in C using double pointer

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, insertion

Hi I'm a newbie learning Linked List, I created this sample program ,but it is not populating all the list, only last two are getting populated (or these overwriting the first linked elements)

Can someone please help me what is causing the issue ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};  

void appendNode(int data, struct node **ptr) {

    struct node *newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->link = NULL;

    if(*ptr == NULL) {
         *ptr = newnode;
    } else {
        while((*ptr)->link != NULL ) {
            *ptr = (*ptr)->link;
        }
        (*ptr)->link = newnode;
    }

}

void printList(struct node *node) 
{ 
  while (node != NULL) 
  { 
     printf(" %d ", node->data); 
     node = node->link; 
  } 
} 

int main() {

    struct node *head = NULL ;

    appendNode(23,&head);
    appendNode(45,&head);
    appendNode(32,&head);
    appendNode(11,&head);
    appendNode(98,&head);
    printList(head);

}
```

Ir prints

```
 11  98
```

What is causing the issue here ?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just keep track of the last node rather than using a `while` loop to scan the whole list every time you want to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are iterating with *the pointer itself* in `appendNode`<sup>**[1]**</sup>. This is changing the list address every time you assign something to `*ptr`, e.g.

```
     *ptr = newnode;
     ...
        *ptr = (*ptr)->link;
```

Each time `*ptr` is assigned the *list address* is changed (both as seen in `appendNode` and in `main()`)

Your list operations are correct, all you need to do is use a *temporary pointer* to iterate over the list (`iter` below)

```
void appendNode (int data, struct node **ptr) {

    struct node *newnode = malloc (sizeof *newnode),
        *iter = *ptr;

    if (!newnode) { /* VALIDATE every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-newnode");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->link = NULL;

    if (iter == NULL) {
        *ptr = newnode;
    }
    else {
        while (iter->link != NULL) {
            iter = iter->link;
        }
        iter->link = newnode;
    }
}
```

(**note** the use of the dereferenced pointer used with `sizeof` to set the type-size. If you use the dereferenced pointer to set the size, you eliminate any mistake in setting the actual type needed. Also, if you allocate -- you must validate -- every time)

With that change (and the following change to `printList`)

```
void printList (struct node *node) 
{ 
    while (node != NULL) 
    { 
        printf(" %d ", node->data); 
        node = node->link; 
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

Your list works just fine, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/lllast2
 23  45  32  11  98
```

**footnotes:**

**1.** While not an error, C generally avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
while((*ptr)->link != NULL ) {
    *ptr = (*ptr)->link;
}
(*ptr)->link = newnode;
```

With:

```
struct node* last = *ptr;
while (last->link) {
    last = last->link;
}
last->link = newnode;
```

Though it might be nice to extract this into its own function:

```
struct node* findLastNode(struct node* ptr) {
    while (ptr->link) {
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Then, inside `appendNode`:

```
struct node* last = findLastNode(*ptr);
last->link = newnode;
```